# SQLite3.dll for x64

Tags: windows, dll, visual-studio-2015, sqlite, .lib

From the download [sqlite.org/download](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), they provide **Precompiled Binaries for Windows** for both x86 and x64.
So, what gets downloaded is a **.def** file and a **.dll** file.
Using this two files you can create the **.lib** file.
**[Command: lib /def:yourfile.def /out:yourfile.lib]**

On creating the **.lib** file and using it as a dependency, things are working fine for x86. But for x64, Visual Studio is showing the error:

#### LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Is anyone else facing this?

Comment: Why a DLL? Just [compile it into your application](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html).

Comment: Thanks.
Also found out where I was going wrong.

While creating the .lib file, weshould be using the following command:
lib /def:sqlite3.def /machine:X64 /out:sqlite3.lib
I was skipping the /machine:X64 option before.

Comment: Please write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out where I was going wrong.

While creating the .lib file, we should be using the following command: 
**lib /def:sqlite3.def /machine:X64 /out:sqlite3.lib**

I was skipping the /machine:X64 option before. 
Better to see what are all the options provided by a command.

Example:
**lib /?**

*The output will be:*

```
usage: LIB [options] [files]

  options:

  /DEF[:filename]
  /ERRORREPORT:{NONE|PROMPT|QUEUE|SEND}
  /EXPORT:symbol
  /EXTRACT:membername
  /INCLUDE:symbol
  /LIBPATH:dir
  /LIST[:filename]
  /LTCG
  /MACHINE:{ARM|ARM64|EBC|X64|X86}
  /NAME:filename
  /NODEFAULTLIB[:library]
  /NOLOGO
  /OUT:filename
  /REMOVE:membername
  /SUBSYSTEM:{BOOT_APPLICATION|CONSOLE|EFI_APPLICATION|
              EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER|EFI_ROM|EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER|
              NATIVE|POSIX|WINDOWS|WINDOWSCE}[,#[.##]]
  /VERBOSE
  /WX[:NO]
```