# Build code using cl and connect to sqlite library

Tags: c++, windows-10, cl

I have a sample code from sqlite website.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I put the code above in test12_sqlite_database.cpp and put sqlite header and source file in include directory. Then I want to build this code using cl.exe. This is the build command:

```
cl /EHsc test12_sqlite_database.cpp /I include /link d:\sqlite\sqlite3.dll
```

The error is:

```
d:\sqlite\sqlite3.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x360
```

After I search the web, it said that I cannot link to dynamic library. So how to use cl so the source can compile successfully and  can use the dynamic library?

Comment: In this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

Comment: Also, for your actual question... try leaving out the `/link`. That's for passing extra options to the linker, and isn't needed for just including a library file (which should be specified just as the filename, just like source files or object files.) Also some light googling suggests you might need to use sqlite3.lib, not sqlite3.dll.

Comment: So not the sqlite website. Good. -- Everything I've seen sqlite related from tutorialspoint has been at best inaccurate and generally demonstrates how not to do things, btw. I wouldn't use it if I were you.

Comment: In https://www.sqlite.org/download.html, there's no download for sqlite3.lib. I search again, it can be created using lib command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623284/sqlite3-dll-for-x64. I'll try this first...

Answer (score 1):

You should not link .dll files but you should link .lib files to your project. It is unclear in question from where you got that sqlite3.dll, why it does not have .lib file for linking it and so on. It does not appear in sqlite.org and so you probably are talking of different site.

The suggested way of using the SQLite library is simply to embed it directly in your application. That means just adding the sqlite3.c and include sqlite3.h files in your project and it should work.

Comment: I get the sqlite3.dll from sqlite.org/download.html, there's no download for sqlite3.lib in that website. But I check in the web you can convert *.dll to *.lib using the *.def file. I have put sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c in the include file. Still failed to build.

Comment: Okay, I put sqlite3.c to the project folder and the project build successfully. The command for the cl is "cl /EHsc test12_sqlite_database.cpp sqlite3.c /I include"

Comment: @roscoe_x that is the only way how I have used it.